# WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%' OR '%chery%' || WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%' or LOWER(description) LIKE '%cherry%'

Tags: mysql

Whats the differences between these two?
Both of them can run without errors but giving me different answer.
Here's the full code for each of them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT winery
FROM winemag_p1
WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%' OR '%chery%' OR '%rose%' OR '%hazelnut%'
ORDER BY winery

SELECT DISTINCT winery
FROM winemag_p1
WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%'
   or LOWER(description) LIKE '%cherry%'
   or LOWER(description) LIKE '%rose%'
   or LOWER(description) LIKE '%hazelnut%'
ORDER BY winery
```

Comment: `OR` doesn't distribute over `LIKE`.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how the answers you get differ.

Comment: Also, there's a typo in 'cherry' in the first version.

Comment: @Barmar and '%cherry%' etc. evaluates to false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OR` doesn't distribute in programming languages like it does in English. `LIKE` has higher precedence than `OR`, so the first condition is equivalent to

```
WHERE (LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%') 
    OR '%chery%' 
    OR '%rose%' 
    OR '%hazelnut%'
```

When you use a literal string in `OR`, it's converted to a number; any string that doesn't begin with a number is converted to `0`, so this becomes equivalent to

```
WHERE (LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%') OR 0 OR 0 OR 0
```

In boolean contexts, `0` is `FALSE` and non-zero is `TRUE`. So,  since `anything OR FALSE` is equivalent to `anything`, the final result is that your condition is equivalent to just

```
WHERE LOWER(description) LIKE '%plum%'
```